# Prevent PHP from attempting to perform mathematical calculations on a string

Tags: php, csv, db2

So I'm using PHP to take the contents of a csv file, put it into a string array and then use SQL to add it to a database on an IBM iSeries.

However PHP keeps trying to treat the contents of the string (which contains special characters like "*" and "-") like a mathematical computation.

How do I prevent this?

here is the code in question

```
if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['uploadcsv']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE)
{
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
      $length = count($data);
      $s_data = implode(',', $data);
      if($length > $maxcol)
      {
        // echo $length;
        // die;
        $uploadMsg = "Data Error: Not ($maxcol) Columns: ($s_data) <br>";
      }
      else
      { 


         if($data[0] <> '')
           {


            $recda[0] = trim($data[0]); // qty = 1 roll


            // Prepare the SQL statement (possibly faster, safer, better practice)
            $insertsql = "INSERT INTO MIKELIB/PALLETS (PALLET) 
                                    VALUES($recda[0]) with nc";

            $stmt = db2_prepare($db2conn, $insertsql);  

            //$result = db2_exec($db2conn, "Insert into file ...$data[0]" 
            $result = db2_execute($stmt, $data[0]);
            if(!$result)
            {
              $uploadMsg .= "Result code: " . $result . "Data Error: " . db2_stmt_error() . " msg: " . db2_stmt_errormsg() . "data: ($s_data)<br>";
              }
            else
            {
            $s_data = implode(',', $recda); 
            $uploadMsg .= "Added row ($s_data)<br>";
            }
          } 
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Here is an example output of the error "Result code: Data Error: 42604 msg: Numeric constant 5D09C not valid. SQLCODE=-103data: (A2501-0044*970*5D09C*034)"

Comment: That has **NOTHING** to do with php, and everything to do with you being vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Please show sample csv data, and table definition.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's your database that is parsing your data as math.

Take a look at this line:

```
$insertsql = "INSERT INTO MIKELIB/PALLETS (PALLET) 
                                    VALUES($recda[0]) with nc";
$stmt = db2_prepare($db2conn, $insertsql);
```

You're putting the values directly into the query, so if the query has math, or invalid symbols, it'll break your query.

What you should do is:

```
$insertsql = "INSERT INTO `MIKELIB/PALLETS` (PALLET) 
                                    VALUES(?) with nc";
$stmt = db2_prepare($db2conn, $insertsql);

$recda0 = $recda[0];
db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, "recda0", DB2_PARAM_IN);
```

That way, there's nothing in `$recda[0]` that will break the query, or be parsed as part of the query.

Comment: I tested your change here however it gives me a 500 server error.

Comment: @JoesphOlliff Try now, I'm using the correct function now. (See updated answer)

Comment: works in that it doesn't cause the server error however I'm not getting an insert or any kind of error response. The error fields are blank and the insert doesn't occur. I have tested the insert manual and it works but I'm not sure what is going wrong here. Is it ok to ask this in the comment or should I update the original question?

Comment: @JoesphOlliff Can you try with backticks around the table name? I'm thinking there might be issues with a slash in the table name.

Comment: Tried backticks and even single quotes both gave the error of invalid tokens, then tried placing MIKELIB/PALLETS into a string and then using the variable name but that just got me back to where I was.

Comment: Is it possible that you have unique constraints on your PALLET column? Can you describe your table?

Comment: Don't put any quotes around table reference. Might try period delimiter, rather than slash.

Answer (score 0):

Joesph, try modifing your SQL to treat that value as a string by wrapping it in single quotes.

$insertsql = "INSERT INTO MIKELIB/PALLETS (PALLET) 
                                    VALUES('$recda[0]') with nc";

You may also need to consider escaping single quotes in the string if there is a possibility it will contain any.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I noticed that and changed it however it now simply gives no error or result, just the insert did not occur.

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression that you may be trying to load values into multiple columns per row.  That won't work in SQL.  You have to specify each column.

I know DB2 for i, but not PHP, so I'll attempt to build on David's answer as a template.

```
$insertsql = "INSERT INTO MYLIB/MYTABLE (cola, colb, colc) 
                                VALUES(?,?,?) with nc";
$stmt = db2_prepare($db2conn, $insertsql);

$vala = $recda[0];
$valb = $recda[1];
$valc = $recda[2];
db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, "vala", DB2_PARAM_IN);
db2_bind_param($stmt, 2, "valb", DB2_PARAM_IN);
db2_bind_param($stmt, 3, "valc", DB2_PARAM_IN);
```

You may need additional PHP code, perhaps to make sure each value is appropriate for its column, and might perhaps need to detect missing values and load a null or default value, depending on your table definition. But I'll leave that to those who know PHP.